# Facebook API - Sort resutls of /taggable_friends endpoint

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

is it possible to return the list of friends (retrieved by the `/taggable_friends` endpoint) in any way sorted by name? At the moment they just get returned in a random order. I couldn't find a query parameter which offers this functionality.

I'm using v2.6 of facebooks API.

Cheers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I couldn't find a query parameter which offers this functionality.

There isn’t one.

Any sorting you will have to do on your end. (And if the user has lots of friends, you will have to paginate through the results first, to get the “full set.”)